# MySql LIKE query works in phpMyAdmin but not in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, pattern-matching

I have a database with some products:

Here are some rows in the database

```
Table name: Products
-------------------------------
product_id   |  product_name
1            |  Coca Cola Zero
2            |  Pepsi Max 0.5L
3            |  Smash Kuler!
-------------------------------
```

My search.php file looks like this

```
$db_handle = new DBcontroller("handlelisten_db");
$searchVal;

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $searchVal = $_GET['id'];

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE  "%'.$searchVal.'%"';
    $res =  $db_handle->runSelectQuery($sql);

    echo(json_encode($res));
}
```

When I try to GET: "localhost/search.php?id=zero"
or "localhost/search.php?id=er" 
the $res array is for some reason empty.

But when I do GET: "localhost/search.php?id=pepsi"
or
"localhost/search.php?id=Smash" 
 i get a correctly formatted json and everything works fine.

Shouldnt the "%"-symbol let me search "er" and get a match with the products with an product_id of 1 and 3?

I cant figure out why the resulting query returns a empty result set.

When I execute the query in phpMyAdmin the result set is returned as expected

Comment: Echo out your $sql to make sure that its what you expect. You're also wide open for SQL injection. I'm not sure if you're using PDO or mysqli, but look into prepared statements and parameter/variable binding.

Comment: if you echo out $sql ,check what you are getting

Comment: I'm using PDO i'm aware of the SQL injection vulnerability.
When I echo out $sql i get

  "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE  "%er%" "

Comment: stupid guess: maybe it needs `'` instead of `"` here?

Comment: Tried that. Works fine bought ways in phpMyAdmin but not in my search.php and some queries works fine like I said. If i input "Pepsi" in the $searchVal I get a result set but not if i do "er"

Comment: If you copy that line exactly and paste it in, does it work? If you can, try turning on logging within mysql (`set general_log = 'on'`) and check the logs to make sure that looks correct, too. Just make sure you remember to turn logging back off!

Comment: can you give it a try without your dbhandler, with direct pdo_query?

Comment: The log shows that the general_log shows that the query is at least correct:

Comment: Tried to upload the app on a live server and it worked fine. For some reason there are some queries when using Mysql on MAMP that dont return a result set even though they should.